# Wordpress Admin And Menu Page Blank

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress 3.4 and i just register a custom post type and taxonomies for it and its working fine but the problem is sometimes some pages shows blank including front-end and back-end

Answer (score 0):

Blank pages are usually caused by PHP errors. Something makes WordPress to crash, and if error display is disabled on your server, all you get is a blank page.

Check your PHP error log for any recent messages. They should point you to the file that contains the problematic code. Usually it will either be a buggy plugin or theme. Alternatively, the error might be caused by WordPress running out of memory. If it's a plugin or theme, you can fix the problem by deactivating it. If it's an "out of memory" error, increase the PHP memory limit.

See also:

- [3 Ways to Monitor PHP Errors in WordPress](http://digwp.com/2009/07/monitor-php-errors-wordpress/)
- [Error Log Monitor plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/error-log-monitor/)
- [Increasing memory allocated to PHP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP)